# Can I load an array from a numeric rel attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

instead of using Id's and manually loading over 35 thumbnail images into an array, I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically create an array based on ordered numeric rel attributes.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <a id="first" class="object" rel="0"></a>
       <a id="second" class="object" rel="1" ></a>
       <a id="third" class="object rowEnd" rel="2" ></a>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var objectArray=new Array();
    objectArray[0]="#first";
    objectArray[1]="#second";
    objectArray[2]="#third";
</script>
```

The above is the html and the manually created array of object id's.

Instead of writing an id tag for each slot in the array I'd like to "automatically" generate an array of all the objects with the ".object" class and unique rel tag attributes.

Comment: What should be the contents of the array? DOM nodes? IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the specific elements you need from the DOM, and iterate over them to populate your array.

In pure JS:

```
var objectArray = [];
var objects = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objectArray[objects[i].rel] = objects[i].id;
}
```

See jsFiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nxJP5/1/